# Efficient way to trim() space characters off all Properties in a JavaScript Object as they are being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

This is a stripped down demo with the very basic needed to replicate what I need to do.

In my JavaScript application I have a **Click event** on **Project Task Records**.

When a Task is clicked on, I populate a JavaScript Object with data from the DOM related to the clicked on Task record.

My problem is that, when I print out the values saved to my object from the DOM, there is always massive space characters in front and behind my strings.

[image]

I have this Shim to utilize the newer built in JavaScript `trim()` function...

```
/* JavaScript trim() method is ES 5, just in case polyfill it (IE 8 and down):
 * example usage:
 *  var str = " a b    c d e   f g   ";
 *  var newStr = str.trim();
*/
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Below I have a simple demo thrown together for this question.

You will see a JavaScript Object stored in `taskDataObject`

> (NOTICE: I realize the actual selector code below is disgusting, that is
>   next on my to-do list!)

This JSFiddle page has all the code to show my demo running:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/2hkz0gp4/

When `.taskName` is clicked on, it grabs data from the DOM and saves it to the `taskDataObject` JavaScript Object.

I am looking for a good way to apply this `str.trim()` code to all the properties in `taskDataObject` and was hoping I wouldn't have to make a bunch of temporary variables.

**Demo code**

```
//Open Task Modal when a Task record is clicked in Task List
$('body').on('click', '.taskName', function() {


    // Set and Cache Task ID from clicked on Task Item
    var taskId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().dataAttr('task-id');

    var $taskEl = $(this);

    // Populate Task Data Object from DOM values
    taskDataObject = {
        //projectId: projectTaskModal.cache.projectId,
        taskId: taskId,
        taskName: $taskEl.text(),
        taskDescription: $taskEl.next('.description').text(),
        taskStatus: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().text(),
        taskPriority: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().text(),
        taskTags: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().text(),
        taskCreatedDate: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().next().text(),
        taskModifiedDate: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().next().next().text(),
        taskDueDate: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().next().next().next().text(),
    };

    console.log('taskDataObject', taskDataObject);


    // Just playing around, this applies the trim() however I had
    // to create a bunch of temp variables and I am not sure if 
    // this can be avoided or done differently?
    for (var key in taskDataObject) {

      if (taskDataObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        alert(key + " -> " + taskDataObject[key]);

        //console.log(key + " -> " + taskDataObject[key]);

          console.log(taskDataObject[key]);

          var tmpVal1 = taskDataObject[key]
          var tmpVal2 = tmpVal1.trim();

          console.log(tmpVal2);

      }
    }

});
```

Comment: `.next().next().next().next().next()`?

Comment: Why not do the trim after `.text().trim()` for each element?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm guessing he is trying to make this code scalable in-case he adds 50 fields to the object. he would have to `.text().trim()` them manually, which is not fun. Alternatively, if these are NOT user inputted strings, then why not `trim()` them when they go into the `td`'s? Then you are guaranteed the `String`'s are trimmed.

Comment: Maybe what should be dynamic is the generation of `taskDataObject`, rather than the fixing. I'd start by refactoring those `next` calls, then OP might find a pattern to abstract, and call `trim` just once.

Comment: @elclanrs I know!  I even put a disclaimer in my post because I know it's pretty horrible, it's something I did a while back when I was in a hurry and didn't know a lot about JavaScript so basically it was the first thing that worked.  I very much want to refactor all those `next()`!  As for dynamic generation of `taskDataObject` I like the sound of it, just not sure how to go about all this...JavaScript is is a learning in process thing for me as i've always been more backend until recently.  I'm loving JavaScript though so i'm soaking in all the comments, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you just need to call `text().trim()` instead of `text()`. `text()` returns a `String`

In case you really need to do the trim for each property value, do:

```
for (var key in taskDataObject) {
    if(taskDataObject[key].trim)
       taskDataObject[key] = taskDataObject[key].trim(); 
}
```

And here is a function to do it recursively, along all child properties:

```
function trimObjectProperties(objectToTrim) {
    for (var key in objectToTrim) {
        if (objectToTrim[key].constructor && objectToTrim[key].constructor == Object)
            trimObjectProperties(objectToTrim[key]);
        else if (objectToTrim[key].trim)
            objectToTrim[key] = objectToTrim[key].trim();
    }
}

// Using this function, you should call it in that way:
trimObjectProperties(taskDataObject);
```

Comment: Probably it will solve his real need, as he says "as they are being set?". It seems to me that he was trying to trim every properties values because isn't known that this could be done at the moment of the set. But you are right. I edited to my answer with the code to do what is asked for.

Comment: Thanks, im curious what the `trim` on the end of this line does? `if(taskDataObject[key].trim)`

Comment: @JasonDavis i'm checking for the existence of this "method" on the property value. Let's suppose that taskId is a Number, if you call taskId.trim() you will get an error, because .trim just exists for Strings

Comment: Thanks!  I almost disregarded that part but it seems I shouldn't!  Do you think there should be some type of check to make sure the property is a string type, or is that basically doing the same thing now?  Thanks

Comment: This also looks nice http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59543/2889 same concrpt but refactored a bit furthor

Comment: @JasonDavis I edited my answer to add a function which will do the job recursively, for all child properties. Something like this answer that you posted on your last comment, but written in a leanest way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have enough comments and answer to your problem, but since you said you're learning js, I though I would bring another perspective to the discussion.

First of all I would like to remind you that jQuery has got a [cross browser trim function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), so you don't need another shim since you're using jQuery.

Another great aspect from jQuery is how easy it can be extended. So you could add you own method:

```
$.fn.extend({
  trimmedText: function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text());
  }
});
```

Then use it anywhere in your code:

```
$(element).trimmedText();
```